# Why is Get-DPMDatasource not recognised in Powershell? (Using DPM Module)

Tags: powershell, scdpm

I am using

```
Import-Module DataProtectionManager
```

To have access to DPM cmdlets in powershell. (DPM Version 2012R2)

Unfortunately, `Get-DPMDatasource` is stating it is an unrecognised cmdlet.

Without getting the Datasource, I am unable to start recovery points, etc.

an example of where I have used this is here:

```
$ds = Get-DPMDatasource $DPMServer | where { $_.Id -eq $DataSourceID } # Get tthe datasource affected
```

Also, I have included a picture. the module imports fine. The powershell ISE recognises the cmdlet, but when running there is no recognition?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is an additional import required for these cmdlets.

Use, `Import-Module DPMExtendedCmdlets`